# Glfw callback with additional variables

Tags: c++, glfw

I have a method which takes `voxContext*` and a callback for `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback`.
My callback function is `void(*inputFunc)(voxContext* ctx, GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)`. I can't use this function pointer in `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback`. Can i change parameter order?

Comment: C does not support _methods_, so you must be using C++. They are different languages, don't spam tags.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to GLFW you usually associate some internal data structure with each window using:

```
void glfwSetWindowUserPointer (GLFWwindow *window, void *pointer);
void* glfwGetWindowUserPointer (GLFWwindow *window);
```

Set user pointer when creating window or whenever and then retrieve and use it in callbacks.

Comment: Oh, so *that's* where the user data pointer is hidden. I was kind of surprised that there be none...